# Locale-aware JavaScript validation

Tags: javascript, locale, currency

Can you suggest a locale-aware way to validate a currency value on the client using Javascript?

Obvious issue to consider: 1,234.56 in the US and UK is the same as 1.234,56 in most of Europe

Sri

Comment: If you can afford to, use a third party control such as telerik's RadNumericTextBox which has locale support (it's built on top of MS AJAX): http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input_radnumerictextbox.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to a free javascript library that can help you with that: [Dojo Currency Formatter](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/HEAD/dojo.currency.format), there's also a similar feature in [ASP.NET Ajax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb310813.aspx).

Comment: Going by the docs this appears to *format* the given number and not validate it.